# Have single color for all words in highcharts word cloud

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am just getting familiar with Highcharts word cloud. I am looking to solve a issue where I can have single color for all words in the word cloud using High charts. For example all words have a color red in the word cloud. I am using the default highcharts [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/wordcloud/) as example.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
series: [{
    type: 'wordcloud',
    data: data,
    name: 'Occurrences' 
}],
title: {
    text: ''
},
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to read [the docs](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colors), 
all you need to do is specify only one color, as follows:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        type: 'wordcloud',
        data: data,
        name: 'Occurrences',
        colors: [ 'red' ]
    }],
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
series: [{
    type: 'wordcloud',
    data: data,
    name: 'Occurrences',
    color: 'red'

}],

plotOptions: {
  wordcloud: { 
               colorByPoint: false

  }
},
title: {
    text: 'Wordcloud of Lorem Ipsum'
} });
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation to your answer, not just a code.